# Notify user who liked my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I have a website that have a like button with url pointing to the website's url. The like button works, but I can't seems to figure out how to send notification to users who like the button. I understand that the admin button for a like button is no longer possible and the migration window is already closed. I should change the URL to a facebook page. But if I change it to a facebook page, then when the user share the link, they will open the facebook page, not my website. So how do I make it possible for the user to share my website, but still be able to notify them of any news.

Comment: That is simply not possible. Only posts on a Facebook page that users have liked may show up in their news feed.

Comment: if people could notify users just because they liked some article on a website, no one would like anything anymore ;)